# Install Unity 4.0 in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) and find Unity 5.0 unfamiliar and sluggish, so I would like to downgrade to Unity 4.0, that was included in Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot). I can't find any working archives of Unity 4.0 and I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: What in particular is unfamiliar and sluggish to you? 5.0 should in general be faster than 4.0. The unity developers (especially Daniel van Vugt) put a lot of effort into making 5.0 faster and fixing performance bugs. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/861061

Answer (score 3):

Oscar, you'd need to grab the source of Unity from Ubuntu 11.10 and re-compile it with the newer libraries in 12.04.

That seems a bit overkill. Perhaps just try unity-2d.